# Wireshark RPC packet capture with localhost

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireshark, google-app-engine, rpc

I want to capture RPC-XML packets on locahost using wireshark.
As RPC-XML is at the top of tcp/udp, I enabled all protocols still I am not able to capture the traffic.  Is there other way to do so?

I created sample RPC application for testing purposes.

Comment: Wireshark listens on an interface (if I recall correctly). In that case of localhost, I have no idea what that interface should be, but that is the issue probably

Comment: this is local interface (loopback address)

Comment: What OS is this?  Loopback capturing is OS specific, and unix encompasses many OSs.

Comment: Os unix flavor : ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

> Os unix flavor : ubuntu

I.e., Linux, so capture on the device named `lo`.